# How to add boost lib to Qt on linux system using qmake?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, boost

main.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_condattr_setclock@@GLIBC_2.3.3'

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Did you try just adding your library to `LIBS`? For instance, `LIBS += -lboost_thread`

Comment: Well, have you looked at the error? You are *not* missing boost. You're missing pthreads. Add `LIBS += -lpthread` to the project :) And start using cmake instead of the horrible qmake files. At least you'll get a broadly useful skill and a build system that's useful for way more than just building Qt projects :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be sure that boost is installed in your system :

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

then in `.pro` you should add this:

```
LIBS +=-lboost_thread
```

**Edited:** all `.pro` File

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target


LIBS += -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_chrono
```

Comment: I have a boost in my system (Manjaro Linux) I tried to link lib as system lib and as binary, but I still have this error could you give all pro how it should look like

Comment: ‍`‍‍‍‍link lib as system lib` means that you use `ln` command?

Comment: you should not link something.

Comment: LIBS += -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_chrono
 It didn't work (((

Comment: you should not link something. " you need just LIBS +=-lboost_thread " but If you just normally install boost and then add this to your project.